# clear selected range cell values on clicking delete button

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to clear all the values of the cells that are in the selected range by clicking delete keyboard button. Can someone tell me how to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution if someone wants to achieve the same.
Register a key down press event in agGrid's onRangeSelectionChanged callback function
`onRangeSelectionChanged={()=>{ window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleDeleteOnRange)}` 
Then, check for delete key press in handleDeleteOnRange, get the selected range of cells using the agGrid's api getCellRanges and delete the values of that cells.

```
handleDeleteOnRange(event) {
    var cellRanges = this.gridApi.getCellRanges();
    var rowData = this.state.rowData;
    if ([46].indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1) { //delete key press
      cellRanges.map((range) => {
        if (range?.startRow?.rowIndex && range?.endRow?.rowIndex) {
          var startRow =
            Math.min(range.startRow.rowIndex, range.endRow.rowIndex);
          var endRow =
            Math.max(range.startRow.rowIndex, range.endRow.rowIndex);
          for (var rowIndex = startRow; rowIndex <= endRow; rowIndex++) {
            range.columns.forEach((column) => {
              if (column.colDef.field !== "row_id") {
                rowData[rowIndex][column.colDef.field] = "";
              }
            });
          }
        }
        this.setState({ rowData: rowData });
        this.gridApi.refreshCells();
      });
    }
  }
```

The above is just a demo code to show how it works.

Don't forget to remove the eventListeners after the job is done.